# is there any case where a variable can be assigned a void function?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm studying for a data structures exam. Going over some exams from previous years, I came upon a question about finding an expression for the run time of the following code:

```
void func(int n) {   
    if(n<=1)    
        return;
    cout << "some string" << endl;

    int x = func(n/2);

    cout << "some other string" << endl;

    int y = func(n/4) + func(n/4);

    for(int i=0; i<2*n; i++)
        cout << i << " x+y+i = " << x+y+i << endl; 

    return;
}
```

The function's name, variable names, strings etc. are changed, but the rest is not.

Is there any special case where the code above would even compile?
I checked it myself on an online visual C++ compiler and got the expected errors regarding treating a void as an int... I'm still very much confused as to how this kind of elementary mistake managed to show up on a CS exam... I'd much rather believe there is some case I'm unfamiliar with in which the above syntax makes sense... either in C/C++ or elsewhere.

Comment: `y = func(n/4) + func(n/4)`, but `func` returns `void` type. :(

Comment: with a public computer you can use this tool: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ ?

Comment: thanks! I used the tool you provided and got the expected errors regarding treating a void as an int...

I'm still very much confused as to how this kind of elementary mistake manages to show up on a CS exam...

Comment: I believe that your question is off topic, because it is a programming question.

Comment: My apologies, I thought programming questions were allowed. Is there a different SE for that?

Comment: I've migrated your question to [so] because it is about C++ programming. If you have questions about the running time, they'd be fine for [cs.se], but you would have to explain the algorithm to an audience who doesn't know C++.

Comment: thanks! I think SO is indeed the more appropriate place for my question

Comment: Why not make it return `int` and return `0` if n<=1? It looks like it's only being used for summation

Comment: I'm not asking how to fix the code. It appeared as above in a question in an exam.

Comment: @guest_undergrad_student Like Neil Kirk said, the code is bad. It won't ever compile because of type mismatch

Comment: The code as presented doesn't make any sense, as in : does not compile. Could it be a trick question?

Comment: "The function's name, variable names, strings etc. are changed"  Are all instances of `func` the same name (even if that name is not `func`) in the original?  Are you 100% positive there is not anything special about the name used in the original?

Comment: @MartinBa I think it makes more sense that it's a mistake in the question. I don't see the point in asking this type of trick question on a data structures exam

Comment: @BenVoigt the original name is "rec", and the code is given as is and on its own

Answer (score 1):

The code, as shown, makes no sense. It relies on the return value of `func`, but `func` doesn't return anything (it's void).

You could have two different functions called `func`, but there needs to be something to tell them apart. The first way would be if they took different parameter types:

```
void func(int);
int func(double);
```

That doesn't appear to be the case here, since you're always calling with an `int`.

The second would be if they were in different namespaces, or if one was a class member and the other wasn't. In that case you'd need to add some syntax.

```
int x = other::func(n/2); // to use the namespace "other"
int x = ::func(n/2);      // to use a global
```

Comment: Thanks!
So it's either a trick question or a mistake in the exam. I figure it was probably a mistake as this kind of trick question wouldn't make much sense in a course on data structures.

Since I'm quite new to programming I just wanted to make sure the code was indeed wrong.